# AngularJS: $routeParams service causes ng-bind-html directive to not work - why?

Tags: json, angularjs

**Update: Here's a [link to my demo](http://ogmda.com/sandbox/#/videos/0)** . The direct link to my view/partial with the issue i[s here](http://view-source:http://ogmda.com/sandbox/partials/videos.html).

I am consuming a JSON feed in my AngularJS app that contains HTML elements in a string that I am trying to bind to the View when using the `$routeParams` service. Without the `$routeParams` service it works, but when I use the `$routeParams` service it doesn't work. *Does anyone know why?*

Here's my hypothetical code:

JSON feed example with HTML element in synopsis value:

```
[{
    "title": "Canada",
    "synopsis": "<p>Lorem ipsum blah blah and blah...</p>"
    ...
    ...
}]
```

My scripts:

```
var ArticApp = angular.module('ArcticApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);

ArcticApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: './partials/map.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
      })

      .when('/videos/:itemId', {
        templateUrl: './partials/videos.html',
        controller: 'VideoController',
      })

      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      })
});

ArcticApp.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'This is the map page';
});

ArcticApp.controller('VideoController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
    $http.get('./database.json').success(function(data){
      $scope.videos = data;
      $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    })
});
```

My View (/partials/videos.html):

```
...
...
    <section ng-bind-html="{{videos[whichItem].synopsis}}"></section>
...
...
```

Removing the `ng-bind-html` directive will show the synopsis text (with the HTML element `<p>`). But, adding the `ng-bind-html` directive will cause the view to not show any text. Completely hidden. If I don't use the `$routeParams` service, the view will correctly sanitize and bind the synopsis text.

**Any ideas on what is going on?**

Comment: Looks like I can use $sce somehow in the controller to make it work., but unsure how to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for `ng-bind-html` is an expression rather than a binding via curly braces `{{ }}`.

So, to correct the first problem:

```
<section ng-bind-html="videos[whichItem].synopsis"></section>
```

You may also need to trust that html using the `$sce` service, so inject `$sce` into the controller and then set this:

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml.bind($sce);
```

and now you may use that function when binding:

```
<section ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(videos[whichItem].synopsis)"></section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It seemed that all I needed to do was fix the first problem by correcting the syntax for the ng-bind-html directive as you mentioned. Doing that worked! I didn't need to do the other 2 steps. However, I'll have to test at the office because that was where I was having issues, not at home where I am testing now. Either way, both methods you metioned here worked! Thanks again, I'll mark this as solved.

Comment: @redshift Are you using the same version of Angular at work?